# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.getClassLoader - after Jenkins version upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-update

We got the error below after a Jenkins upgrade. Any idea what could be the cause this error?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.getClassLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.<init>(FactoryProvider2.java:322)
    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:334)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:64)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:106)
    at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule.configure(RestModule.java:59)
    at org.jclouds.rest.config.HttpApiModule.configure(HttpApiModule.java:53)
    at org.jclouds.s3.config.S3HttpApiModule.configure(S3HttpApiModule.java:169)
    at org.jclouds.aws.s3.config.AWSS3HttpApiModule.configure(AWSS3HttpApiModule.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:64)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:405)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:328)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:615)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:595)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.artifact_manager_jclouds.s3.S3BlobStore.getContext(S3BlobStore.java:136)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.artifact_manager_jclouds.JCloudsArtifactManager.getContext(JCloudsArtifactManager.java:377)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.artifact_manager_jclouds.JCloudsArtifactManager.stash(JCloudsArtifactManager.java:216)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.StashManager.stash(StashManager.java:117)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.file_parameters.StashedFileParameterValue.buildEnvironment(StashedFileParameterValue.java:71)
    at hudson.model.ParametersAction.buildEnvironment(ParametersAction.java:143)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2439)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.getEnvironment(WorkflowRun.java:500)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:310)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```